# Erro ao executar migration

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Erro:

> 1005 Can't create table 'cobranca_simples.#sql-f04_1f0' (errno: 150)
>   (SQL: alter table `carteira_cliente` add constraint
>   `carteira_cliente_carteira_id_foreign` foreign key (`carteira_id`)
>   references `carteiras` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Migrations:

```
Schema::create('carteiras', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id');
        $table->string('descricao');
        $table->timestamps();
    }
);

Schema::create('carteira_cliente', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('carteira_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('cliente_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('carteira_id')->references('id')
                        ->on('carteiras')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('cliente_id')->references('id')
                        ->on('clientes')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['carteira_id', 'cliente_id']);
    }
);
Schema::create('carteira_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('carteira_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('carteira_id')->references('id')
                        ->on('carteiras')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
                        ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['carteira_id', 'user_id']);
    }
);
```

Comment: E onde está a migration da tabela `cobranca_simples`?

Comment: cobranca_simples é o nome do banco

Comment: Deve ser a ordem de criação, se fez errado tem que mudar o nome do arquivo. é uma suposição somente, só isso não tem como saber, é um erro local de difícil reprodução.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, bem simples resolver.

```
carteiras.id tem sinal 
carteira_cliente.carteira_id não tem sinal (unsigned)
```

Ambas devem ser iguais.

Respondendo ao comentário do amigo Thalles Rangel, de forma mais detalhada.

Segundo a [documentação oficial do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), as colunas correspondentes devem ser do mesmo tipo. Para inteiros, o sinal e comprimento devem ser iguais. Para strings, o comprimento não precisa ser igual. Para strings não binárias, o charset e collation devem ser iguais.

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

Em termos práticos, imagine um banco com as tabelas "city" e "country".

[image: address]

Então se a tabela/coluna **country.country_id** é um SMALLINT UNSIGNED, então a tabela/coluna **city.country_id** também deve ser um SMALLINT UNSIGNED.

Sinais em campos numéricos indicam se o número irá ou não possuir um valor negativo.

Olhe a [tabela de inteiros do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html):

O SMALLINT do meu exemplo, com sinal possui um range de -32768 ~ 32767. Já sem sinal (UNSIGNED) possui um range de 0 ~ 65535.

Então ali na migration, **carteiras.id** tem sinal (valor negativo), e **carteira_cliente.carteira_id** não tem sinal (somente valor positivo). Portanto tem sinais diferentes e origina o erro.

O correto seria:

```
Schema::create('carteiras', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('id');
        //ou se for chave primária com auto incremento 
        //$table->increments('id'); 
        $table->string('descricao');
        $table->timestamps();
    }
);
```

Espero ter esclarecido.

Abraços.

Comment: poderia esclarecer melhor, não entendi sua sugestão..